# How to write stack programs for arithmetic terms?

Tags: programming-languages

I have been given a question about a stack program which I can not solve.

> Write a stack program to evaluate the term
>
> $\qquad (((A+B)-(A*B))*C)/(((A-B-C))⁄2)$

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: Check for reverse polish notation

Comment: what is the reverse polish notation? it is important ?

Comment: hint: it might help to change the representation of the equation before feeding it to your program

Comment: may be if i put A=3,B=2,C=4 Then first i find the (A+B)-(A*B)*C = R1

Comment: then i find (A-B-C)/2 =R2 >>>>>>>>after that i division r1 by r2

Comment: but how i write the code of stack program ?

Comment: hint: try a simpler equation first. heed bartek's advice.

Comment: 1) Please include more of your own thoughts in the question; see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question). 2) This is essentially a *programming* question, which are offtopic here. Since you want to program in an abstract model/language, it's fine, though.

Comment: @collapsar: Changing the representation may not be allowed.

Comment: @raphael: you're right (it might still help to get on track)

Comment: i still i cant solve it :( (how i add operations of stack like PUSH TOP POP (I have Constance )

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is; either first translate the expression into something that is easier for a stack machine to handle (like reverse polish).

The other is to use a modified [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) which can handle parenthesis.

You have 2 stacks: a result stack that holds the numbers where you push the numbers as you encounter them;

and an operator stack that holds operators in decreasing priority order.

When you need to add a operator that is of lower precedence you pop from the operator stack. Then apply that operator to the top 2 values on the result stack and replace them with the result. A parenthesis is of lowest priority but is the only one that can go on top of a higher priority operator.

When you encounter a closing parenthesis you pop from the operator stack and apply to the result stack until you find a closing parenthesis which you pop.

Comment: Please try to adhere to common styling courtesy, e.g. punctuation and capitalisation.

Comment: i still not understand